# Class not in namespace

Tags: php, contao

I am trying to create a hook extension for Contao.
But Contao doesn't seem to be able to load my class from the namespace, which handles the hook.
This is my file structure:

[image]

I have tried changing names and added ".php" to the class, looked up tutorials, but I can't find what I am doing wrong. I am fairly inexperienced in this topic, so I might be missing something obvious.

**autoload.php**

```php
ClassLoader::addNamespaces(array 
    ( 
        'Memberlevels', 
    )); 

gister PSR-0 namespace 
 */ 
if (class_exists('NamespaceClassLoader')) { 
    NamespaceClassLoader::add('Memberlevels', 'system/modules/memberlevels/classes'); 
} 


if (class_exists('NamespaceClassLoader')) { 
    NamespaceClassLoader::addClassMap(array 
        ( 

            'Memberlevels'                => 'system/modules/memberlevels/classes/myClass.php' 
        )); 
} 

/* 
 * Register the templates 
 */ 
TemplateLoader::addFiles([ 
    'cookiebar' => 'system/modules/memberlevels/templates', 
]);
```

config.php

```php
$GLOBALS['TL_HOOKS']['outputBackendTemplate'][] = array('Memberlevels\myClass', 'myOutputBackendTemplate');
```

I get the error message:

> Attempted to load class "myClass" from namespace "Memberlevels". Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are still using the old Contao 3 way of loading classes. In Contao 4, you should use the autoloading feature of composer. The default `composer.json` of the most recent Contao versions already include autoloading directives for the `src/` folder of your Contao installation:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "src/"
    }
},
```

Using that, this is how you create & register a hook in a Contao 4.4 compatible way:

```
// src/EventListener/OutputBackendTemplateListener.php

namespace App\EventListener;

class OutputBackendTemplateListener
{
    public function onOutputBackendTemplate(string $buffer, string $template): string
    {
        // Do something 
        return $buffer;
    }
}
```

```
// app/Resources/contao/config/config.php

$GLOBALS['TL_HOOKS']['outputBackendTemplate'][] = [\App\EventListener\OutputBackendTemplateListener::class, 'onOutputBackendTemplate'];
```

Starting with Contao 4.8 you can also use annotations to register a hook, eliminating the need to register the hook in `app/Resources/contao/config/config.php`.

Comment: So, Contao 3 Extensions don't work if i copy them to a Contao 4.4 System? I thought they were compatible. At least when it comes to hooks.

Comment: I added the composer.json but the only change is, that the error now showsd in the log, and not as a displayed error in the backend.

Comment: I did not say that Contao 3 extensions do not work in Contao 4. I merely said that you are still using the old way and I showed you the recommended way ;)

Comment: Ah, i see. But you don't know what actually the problem is?

Comment: The problem might be, that you are using the _NamespaceClassLoader_. If you still want to load the classes like in Contao 3, you probably have to do it without the _NamespaceClassLoader_ extension (unless you installed it as well - which I would not recommend anyway).

Comment: I now add the namespaces like in the first 4 lines. Doesn't work as well.

Comment: What do you mean "like in the first 4 lines"?

Comment: If you are still trying the old way - this is how you load classes in Contao 3: https://github.com/contao/core/blob/e38d7e62fef58a73bfcd7a96fe6f303073808d01/system/modules/core/config/autoload.php#L12-L259

Comment: I just converted this extension into a bundle Link here:https://github.com/localbranding-de/membershiplevels-bundle
I have tried setting up the namespaces like you said, but i still get the same error.
I seem to get something real wrong when it comes to namespaces here.

Comment: You are using a classmap in your `composer.json`. Don't put any classes in `src/Resources/contao`. Use your defined namespace.

Comment: So i put the classes folder in src? And remove the classmap? And i see plenty of extensions that have their classes for hooks and stuff in    src/Resources/contao

Comment: Just do it like in my example. A class for a hook should go into the `EventListener` namespace for example. Technically it does not matter where the class is - you are free to define your classes anywhere. But it makes sense to keep a certain structure. Also you should follow basic PHP coding guidlines. For instance, your class should not be called `honischClass`. First of all you should use camel case, secondly your class name should reflect on what the class actually does.

Comment: I build it the way you suggested, but the error stays `Attempted to load class "OutputBackendTemplateListener::class" from namespace "LocalbrandingDe\MembershiplevelsBundle\EventListener". Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?`

Comment: It should work, as far as I can see. Remember to not use the `--optimize-autoloader` option during the development. If you ran your `composer update` or `install` operation with `-o`/`--optimize-autoloader`, you need to run `composer dump-autoload`.

Comment: I use `php contao-manager.phar.php composer update --prefer-dist` to install/update the package. The hello world module is working fine (it does get displayed in the frontend). Also when i dublicate the `OutoutBackendTemplateListener` i get the error message, that the class name is already in use. So it has to be registered somewhere, just not the namespace i want apperently.

Comment: You made a syntactical error. you wrote `['LocalbrandingDe\MembershiplevelsBundle\EventListener\OutputBackendTemplateListener::class', 'myOutputBackendTemplate'];`, but it should be either `['LocalbrandingDe\MembershiplevelsBundle\EventListener\OutputBackendTemplateListener', 'myOutputBackendTemplate'];` or `[\LocalbrandingDe\MembershiplevelsBundle\EventListener\OutputBackendTemplateListener::class, 'myOutputBackendTemplate'];`

Comment: Ah, yes. It works. Thank you. So it needs  string (example 1) or an object (example 2). That was probably it, and there was nothing wrong with the namespaces.

Comment: The second example is also a string :). Using `::class` resolves the class name to a string.